# Formatting output with "stdWrap.parseFunc.short" in Extension (pw_teaser) - Typo3

Tags: typescript

in Typo3 I'm using `page.stdWrap.parseFunc.short {}`  to generate some specials formattings.

The parsFunc works fine but not on the content which is generated by the extension (tx_pwteaser). (In this case the `nav_title`)

How can I activate this function?